# How can I change default behavior of blueprint's menu item?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, blueprint

[image]

For my react project's Menu I used MenuItem from '@blueprintjs/core'
and as shown in the image, when I hover Menu item which has children, they  open from right side. Is there a way to change that and open child submenu under its parent item?

```
import React from 'react';
import { MenuItem } from '@blueprintjs/core';
import Style from './styled';

const leftMenu = () => {

const Items = createNav.map(menuItem => {
    let children;
    if ('children' in menuItem) {
        children = menuItem.children.map(child => {
            return (
                <MenuItem
                    icon={child.icon}
                    text={child.title}
                    href={child.path}
                    key={menuItem.path}
                    />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <Style.MenuItem
                icon={menuItem.icon}
                text={menuItem.title}
                href={menuItem.path}
                key={menuItem.path}
            >
                {children}
            </Style.MenuItem>
        );
    });
    return <Style.Menu>{Items}</Style.Menu>;
};

export default LeftMenu;
```

for styling I use styled-components

```
 const Menu = styled(bpMenu)`
     padding: 0 !important;
     background-color: transparent !important;
`;

const MenuItem = styled(Item)`
     background-color: red ;
     margin: 5px;
`;
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this? From what I see, I assume you need an accordion.

Answer (score 0):

is it opening automatically? I was facing an issue, the submenus were getting opened automatically even though neither I hovered nor clicked!!!

then added `autoFocus={false}` in popover2. here is my code sample

```
<Popover2
     content={
       <>
        <Menu key="menu">
          <MenuItem icon="camera" text="Menu 1"></MenuItem>
          <MenuItem icon="dollar" text="Menu 2" disabled={true} />
          <MenuItem  icon="lifesaver" text="Football">
               <MenuItem icon="chart" text="Team 1" />
               <MenuItem icon="chart" text="Team 2" />
               <MenuItem icon="chart" text="Team 3" />
         </MenuItem>                                        
       </Menu>
      </>
     }
     position="bottom"
     interactionKind="hover"
     autoFocus={false}
>
     <Button
         text="vivid..."
         minimal
         large={false}
         className="b f5 white _btn_"
         intent="none"
         icon="share"
     />
</Popover2>
```

And for navBar styling, you can also follow the [navBar](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/navbar) of blueprintjs